# Interfacing CH376s with Arduino Nano Every

Tags: arduino, usb, serial

I am trying to interface CH376S with Arduino to send the data to USB connected to CH376S module I am using a USB 2.0 with storage capacity of 16GB , I have also formatted the USB to FAT32 . I am using Ch376msc library which I have downloaded from Arduino Library Manager ,From that library I am using basicUsageSoftSerial example , I Connected RX of CH376S module to pin 6 of Arduino Nano every and TX of CH376S module to pin 7 of Arduino Nano every .When i upload the program ,the program is getting uploaded without any error and when I attach the USB to the module I get Fash is Attached . I am able to Create a TEXT file and append data to USB and also read data from the USB via Arduino Serial Monitor but when i connect to same USB to my Computer i don't see any TEXT file in the USB, I am not able to figure out what the issue is ?

Comment: What name did you make the file? Can you read a text file that was put on the USB stick by your computer?

Comment: text.txt was the name of the file

Comment: Install this disk editor program:- https://www.disk-editor.org/index.html Examine the USB drive 'physical disk'. What do you see in the boot sector? Navigate to the root directory. Do you see your file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an a known issue. Your module have an outdated Firmware (revision number less than 0x43, use the getChipVer() function to find out your version). Do not format the usb drive with the Win10 format tool, use a third-party application for that, example: [Active@ Partition Manager](https://www.lsoft.net/partition-manager/index.html). You can find more information on the library GitHub page [HERE](https://github.com/djuseeq/Ch376msc#firmware-difference)

Comment: Can you expand this answer? If the link goes dead this answer will be worthless

Comment: this worked for me thanks @djusee